# Three divs side by side responsive

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out where I'm making mistake. I have three divs (actually ul li) and I want to make them responsive. Divs need to be side by side from 1180px to 500px and after 500px (smaller than 500px) divs need to be 100% width and one below another and I made it. Only problem is how to make them side by side from 1180px to 500px? Here is the code

```
<section class="portfolio">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio_item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="portfolio_title">
                        <h3>LEFT</h3> 
                    </div><!-- end portfolio_title  !-->
                </div><!-- end portfolio_item  !-->
            </li><!-- end li !-->
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio_item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="portfolio_title">
                        <h3>MIDDLE</h3> 
                    </div><!-- end portfolio_title  !-->
                </div><!-- end portfolio_item  !-->
            </li><!-- end li !-->
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio_item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="portfolio_title">
                        <h3>RIGHT</h3> 
                    </div><!-- end portfolio_title  !-->
                </div><!-- end portfolio_item  !-->
            </li><!-- end li !-->
        </ul><!--  end ul  !-->
    </div><!--  end wrapper  !-->
</section><!--  end section portfolio  !-->

.wrapper {
    width: 1180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.portfolio {
    margin: 100px auto 38px auto;
}
.portfolio ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -62px;
}
.portfolio ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 62px;
    margin-bottom: 62px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 352px;
    height: 334px;
}
.portfolio ul li .portfolio_item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .portfolio ul {
        margin-left: -5.2542372881355932203389830508475%;
    }
    .portfolio ul li {
        margin-left: 5.2542372881355932203389830508475%;
        margin-bottom: 5.2542372881355932203389830508475%;
        width: 29.830508474576271186440677966102%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .portfolio ul {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .portfolio ul li {
        margin-bottom: 5.2542372881355932203389830508475%;
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.wrapper` is 1180px width. The width of the contained `.portfolio ul li` is 352px. But they also come with a margin-left of 62px.

Since they are three elements, (352 + 62) x 3 = 1242px and hence they don't fit in the 1180 wrapper.

Either decrease the width or the margin (or make them percentage based.) [In this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdpbLp), I changed the `.portfolio ul li` width to 331px each, and now the 3 elements fit side by side.

Edit: the previous fix works over 1180px. To have a responsive solution between 500px and 1180px, this tweak, in the widths of the `@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {` part, would do the trick:

```
.portfolio ul {
    /* Using full space in the container */
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left:0;
}
.portfolio ul li {
    /* Making sure the 3 elements width and margin add up to 100%
   (2.5 + 2.5 + 28) x 3 =~ 100%   */
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    width: 28%;
    height: auto;      
}
```

That is working [in this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jdpbmv?editors=110).

Comment: You're welcome! I've expanded the solution so the margins and widths add up to 100 and make it responsive also under 1180px.